# Installing sf on RHEL8

Tags: r, linux, rhel8

When I try to install the sf R package, it says that it is not possible to install the rgdal R package even when gdal is installed. How can I fix this?

Here is the relevant information

## Session info

```
$ gdalinfo --version
gdalinfo: /usr/pgsql-14/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib64/libgdal.so.26)
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

```
$ R
Tracing function "install.packages" in package "utils"
> devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
setting  value
version  R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
os       Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)
system   x86_64, linux-gnu
ui       X11
language (EN)
collate  en_CA.UTF-8
ctype    en_CA.UTF-8
tz       America/Chicago
date     2023-09-07
pandoc   NA

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
package     * version date (UTC) lib source
bspm          0.5.3   2023-07-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
cachem        1.0.8   2023-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
callr         3.7.3   2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
cli           3.6.1   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
crayon        1.5.2   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
devtools      2.4.5   2022-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
digest        0.6.33  2023-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
fs            1.6.3   2023-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
htmltools     0.5.5   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
htmlwidgets   1.6.2   2023-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
httpuv        1.6.11  2023-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
later         1.3.1   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
miniUI        0.1.1.1 2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
pkgbuild      1.4.2   2023-06-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
pkgload       1.3.2.1 2023-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
processx      3.8.2   2023-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
profvis       0.3.8   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
promises      1.2.0.1 2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
ps            1.7.5   2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
purrr         1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
Rcpp          1.0.11  2023-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
remotes       2.4.2.1 2023-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
rlang         1.1.1   2023-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
shiny         1.7.4.1 2023-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
stringi       1.7.12  2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
stringr       1.5.0   2022-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
urlchecker    1.0.1   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
usethis       2.2.2   2023-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
vctrs         0.6.3   2023-06-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.1)

[1] /usr/lib64/R/library
[2] /usr/share/R/library
```

## Package installation

```
> install.packages("sf")
Available system packages as root...
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64                                                      62 kB/s |  30 kB     00:00     
PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                 215  B/s | 195  B     00:00     
PostgreSQL 15 for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                          278  B/s | 195  B     00:00     
PostgreSQL 14 for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                          172  B/s | 195  B     00:01     
PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                          281  B/s | 195  B     00:00     
PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                          180  B/s | 195  B     00:01     
PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL / Rocky 8 - x86_64                                                          268  B/s | 195  B     00:00     
Nagios8                                                                                             48 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00     
EPEL 8 RPMs x86_64                                                                                  62 kB/s | 2.4 kB     00:00     
Splunk Universal Forwarder RPMs x86_64                                                              57 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                            78 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:00     
Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.7 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                                50 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                               51 kB/s | 2.4 kB     00:00     
Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                            61 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:00     
Nagios8                                                                                             43 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00     
EPEL 8 RPMs x86_64                                                                                  61 kB/s | 2.4 kB     00:00     
Splunk Universal Forwarder RPMs x86_64                                                              49 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                            61 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:00     
Red Hat Satellite Tools 6.7 for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                                49 kB/s | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                               61 kB/s | 2.4 kB     00:00     
Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)                                            72 kB/s | 2.8 kB     00:00     
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/sf_1.0-14.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3488161 bytes (3.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 MB

Loading required package: utils
Tracing function "install.packages" in package "utils"
* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Loading required package: utils
Tracing function "install.packages" in package "utils"
configure: CC: gcc
configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++17
checking for gdal-config... /bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 3.0.4
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.1... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...  
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... no
checking GDAL: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQcmdStatus@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQfname@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQsetNoticeProcessor@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQftable@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQstatus@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQftablecol@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQconnectdb@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQescapeStringConn@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `lo_close@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQputCopyEnd@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQgetvalue@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQgetisnull@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQftype@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQfmod@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `lo_creat@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `lo_read@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQexec@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQsetClientEncoding@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQgetlength@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQputCopyData@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQgetResult@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `lo_write@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQfinish@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQclear@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQnfields@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `lo_open@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQexecParams@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQntuples@RHPG_9.6'
/usr/lib64/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `PQresultErrorMessage@RHPG_9.6'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/bin/ld: cannot find -larmadillo
/bin/ld: cannot find -lpoppler
/bin/ld: cannot find -ljson-c
/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreexl
/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebp
/bin/ld: cannot find -lkmlbase
/bin/ld: cannot find -lkmldom
/bin/ld: cannot find -lkmlengine
/bin/ld: cannot find -lkmlxsd
/bin/ld: cannot find -lkmlregionator
/bin/ld: cannot find -lxerces-c
/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenjp2
/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdf
/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
/bin/ld: cannot find -lmfhdf
/bin/ld: cannot find -ldf
/bin/ld: cannot find -logdi
/bin/ld: cannot find -lgif
/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeotiff
/bin/ld: cannot find -lgta
/bin/ld: cannot find -lcfitsio
/bin/ld: cannot find -ldapclient
/bin/ld: cannot find -ldapserver
/bin/ld: cannot find -ldap
/bin/ld: cannot find -lspatialite
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/sf’

The downloaded source packages are in
       ‘/tmp/Rtmpc3Qg7t/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("sf") :
 installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
```